# How is std::has_virtual_destructor implemented?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

How can `std::has_virtual_destructor` and similar checks be implemented? I've tried looking at `type_traits` header in Visual Studio, but there's too many macros and templates to even get an idea. Can this check be expressed in any reasonably simple form? I'd love to at least know the principle of its working, because right now I have no idea.

Comment: It's compiler magic. You can't implement this in standard C++. Boost provides this trait class, and they use compiler specific intrinsics. Check [this header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/type_traits/intrinsics.hpp) out.

Comment: @jrok: are you sure? Why is it not a compiler keyword then? BTW, I'm pretty sure Boost had it prior to C++0x compilers.

Comment: @jrok Any technology distinguishable from magic is insufficiently advanced :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many of the type traits require compiler magic: the traits essentially give a library interface to some hooks provided by the different compilers. How the compilers implement these hooks is entirely up to them and there is no consistant interface.

At the current meeting there was discussion on adding reflection to a future revision which may eventually lead to a library implementation if traits like `std::has_virtual_destructor<T>`. However, it will be a while before something like reflection emerges.

Comment: Why would they not standardize the interface of said hooks over so many years?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Didn't they just do that?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: you can consider the traits interface to be the hooks. In practice, the compiler venders have different approach to actually expose the functionality and although I asked around many years ago to create a consistent interface, compiler vendors stated that having to abide to a specific approach would be too constraining.

Comment: @jrok: with the `type_traits` templates? I don't believe so, if they did - this question would have a concrete answer, a single implementation would work with any standard-compliant compiler.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe At some point there has got to be an abstraction layer that hides different approaches of different compilers. It just happens that `std::has_virtual_destructor` is that layer. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe By following your logic, there should only be one implementation of other parts of the standard library as well. But there are many, some of them using compiler intrinsics for performance, safety or other reasons. From the point of view of the language, the interface is standardised.